# Snowflake Tasks causing error in timezone in queries

Tags: stored-procedures, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running a simple insert query inside a stored procedure with `to_timeatamp_ntz("column value")` along with other columns.
This works fine when I am running it with the snowflake UI and logged in with my account.
This works fine when I am calling it using python scripts from my visual studio instance.
The same stored procedure fails when it is being called by a scheduled task.
I am thinking if it has something to do with the user's timezone of 'System' vs my time zone.

> Execution error in store procedure LOAD_Data(): Failed to cast variant
>   value "2019-11-27T13:42:03.221Z" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ At
>   Statement.execute, line 24 position 57

I tried to provide timezone as session parameters in task and in the stored proc but does not seem to be addressing the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I did a task with "INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP(T1) SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2019-11-27T13:42:03.221Z');" where the column was NTZ_TIMESTAMP(9) and it ran successfully.  Am I missing something to repro?  Let me know if you can setup a similar very simple task and see if it works. I wonder if it's specific to parameters or data.

Comment: Since you get an error message from the `Statement.execute()` call it would have been useful to include the statement that generates the error.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the stored proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
my Task was using a copy paste effect similar to this:

```
CREATE TASK TASK_LOAD_an_sp
  WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
  TIMEZONE = 'US/Eastern'  
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON  0/30 * * * * America/New_York'
  TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
AS
    Call LOAD_an_sp();
```

The Timestamp input format was causing this.

Comment: So you removed `TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT` from task ddl and worked? I am having the same issue, I guess when setting it all data having time with different format will be ignored or an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (since you didn't include the SQL statement that causes the error) that you are trying to bind a `Date` object when creating a `Statement` object.  That won't work.

The only parameters you can bind are numbers, strings, `null`, and the special `SfDate` object that you can only get from a result set (to my knowledge).  Most other parameters must be converted to `string` using `mydate.toJSON()`, `JSON.stringify(myobj)`, etc., before binding, eg:

```
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
   { sqlText: `SELECT :1::TIMESTAMP_LTZ NOW`, binds: [(new Date).toJSON()] }
);
```

`Date` object errors can be misleading, because `Date` objects causing an error can be converted and displayed as strings in the error message.